# How to create dynamic number of  image slider within jsp looping

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I want to create the jquery image sliders within jsp loop .With this coding , only the first loop has rotating banner and the other don't work. As I am new to jquery and Pls suggest how it works ?  Source of image slider is http://menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

```
<s:iterator value="models" status="modelStatus">
  <div id="sliderFrame">
      <div id="ribbon"></div>
          <div id="slider">
               <a href="#">  <img src="/includes/dimages/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
               <img src="/includes/dimages/image-slider-3.jpg" alt="" />
               <img src="/includes/dimages/image-slider-4.jpg" alt="" /> 
               <img src="/includes/dimages/image-slider-5.jpg" />
           </div>

      </div> 
  </div> 

</s:iterator>
```

Below is the javascript that I used.

=======================Javascript===================

```
var sliderOptions=
{
    sliderId: "slider",
    effect: "series1",
    effectRandom: false,
    pauseTime: 2600,
    transitionTime: 500,
    slices: 12,
    boxes: 8,
    hoverPause: true,
    autoAdvance: true,
    captionOpacity: 0.3,
    captionEffect: "fade",
    thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
    m:true,
    license: "free"
};

var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);

/* Menucool Javascript Image Slider v2012.9.11. Copyright www.menucool.com */
function mcImgSlider(g){var B=function(a){return document.getElementById(a)},H=function(d){var a=d.childNodes,c=[];if(a)for(var b=0,e=a.length;b<e;b++)a[b].nodeType==1&&c.push(a[b]);return c},J=function(a,b){return a.getElementsByTagName(b)},X=function(a){for(var c,d,b=a.length;b;c=parseInt(Math.random()*b),d=a[--b],a[b]=a[c],a[c]=d);return a},W=function(a,c,b){if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(c,b,false);else a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+c,b)},Z=document,V=function(c,a,b){return b?c.substring(a,b):c.substring(a)},c="style",I="display",t="visibility",e="width",q="height",E="top",A="background",s=function(){this.d=[];this.b=null;this.c()};function Q(){var c=50,a=navigator.userAgent,b;if((b=a.indexOf("MSIE "))!=-1)c=parseInt(a.substring(b+5,a.indexOf(".",b)));if(a.indexOf("Safari")!=-1&&a.indexOf("Chrome")==-1)c=300;return c}var S=Q()<9,x=function(a,b){if(a){a.o=b;if(S)a[c].filter="alpha(opacity="+b*100+")";else a[c].opacity=b}};s.a={f:function(a){return-Math.cos(a*Math.PI)/2+.5},g:function(a){return a},h:function(b,a){return Math.pow(b,a*2)},j:function(b,a){return 1-Math.pow(1-b,a*2)}};s.prototype={k:{c:g.transitionTime,a:function(){},b:s.a.f,d:1},c:function(){for(var b=["webkit","ms","o"],a=0;a<b.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame;++a){window.requestAnimationFrame=window[b[a]+"RequestAnimationFrame"];window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[b[a]+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[b[a]+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"]}this.e=!!window.requestAnimationFrame},m:function(h,d,g,c){for(var b=[],i=g-d,j=g>d?1:-1,f=Math.ceil(60*c.c/1e3),a,e=1;e<=f;e++){a=d+c.b(e/f,c.d)*i;if(h!="opacity")a=Math.round(a);b.push(a)}b.index=0;return b},n:function(){this.b==null&&this.p()},p:function(){this.q();var a=this;this.b=this.e?window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){a.p()}):window.setInterval(function(){a.q()},15)},q:function(){var a=this.d.length;if(a){for(var c=0;c<a;c++)this.o(this.d[c]);while(a--){var b=this.d[a];if(b.d.index==b.d.length){b.c();this.d.splice(a,1)}}}else{if(this.e&&window.cancelAnimationFrame)window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.b);else window.clearInterval(this.b);this.b=null}},o:function(a){if(a.d.index<a.d.length){var d=a.b,b=a.d[a.d.index];if(a.b=="opacity"){if(S){d="filter";b="alpha(opacity="+Math.round(b*100)+")"}}else b+="px";a.a[c][d]=b;a.d.index++}},r:function(e,b,d,f,a){a=this.s(this.k,a);var c=this.m(b,d,f,a);this.d.push({a:e,b:b,d:c,c:a.a});this.n()},s:function(c,b){b=b||{};var a,d={};for(a in c)d[a]=b[a]!==undefined?b[a]:c[a];return d}};var f=new s,b={a:0,e:"",d:0,c:0,b:0},a,d,o,r,C,y,D,h,k,G,w,n,u,v,m,L,F,l,j=null,O=function(b){if(b=="series1")a.a=[6,8,15,2,5,14,13,3,7,4,14,1,13,15];else if(b=="series2")a.a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];else a.a=b.split(/\W+/);a.a.p=g.effectRandom?-1:a.a.length==1?0:1},K=function(){a={b:g.pauseTime,c:g.transitionTime,f:g.slices,g:g.boxes,O0:g.license||"5432",h:g.hoverPause,i:g.autoAdvance,j:g.captionOpacity,k:g.captionEffect=="none"?0:g.captionEffect=="fade"?1:2,l:g.thumbnailsWrapperId,Ob:function(){typeof beforeSlideChange!=="undefined"&&beforeSlideChange(arguments)},Oa:function(){typeof afterSlideChange!=="undefined"&&afterSlideChange(arguments)}};if(d)a.m=Math.ceil(d.offsetHeight*a.g/d.offsetWidth);O(g.effect);a.n=function(){var b;if(a.a.p==-1)b=a.a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.a.length)];else{b=a.a[a.a.p];a.a.p++;if(a.a.p>=a.a.length)a.a.p=0}if(b<1||b>17)b=15;return b}},bb=["$1$2$3","$1$2$3","$1$24","$1$23"],p=[];function T(){var e;if(a.l)e=B(a.l);if(e)for(var f=e.childNodes,d=0;d<f.length;d++)f[d].className=="thumb"&&p.push(f[d]);var c=p.length;if(c){while(c--){p[c].on=0;p[c].i=c;p[c].onclick=function(){j.y(this.i)};p[c].onmouseover=function(){this.on=1;this.className="thumb thumb-on"};p[c].onmouseout=function(){this.on=0;this.className=this.i==b.a?"thumb thumb-on":"thumb"}}P(0)}}function P(b){var a=p.length;if(a)while(a--)p[a].className=a!=b&&p[a].on==0?"thumb":"thumb thumb-on"}function U(b){var a=[],c=b.length;while(c--)a.push(String.fromCharCode(b[c]));return a.join("")}var M=function(a,g,i,c,b,d,h){setTimeout(function(){if(g&&i==g-1){var h={};h.a=function(){j.o()};for(var k in a)h[k]=a[k]}else h=a;b[e]!==undefined&&f.r(c,"width",b[e],d[e],a);b[q]!==undefined&&f.r(c,"height",b[q],d[q],a);f.r(c,"opacity",b.opacity,d.opacity,h)},h)},R=function(a){d=a;this.b=0;this.c()},ab=[/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])\.(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/^(?:.*\.)?(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])([\w\-])\.com\.[^.]+$/],z=function(b){var a=document.createElement("div");a.className=b;return a};R.prototype={c:function(){o=d.offsetWidth;r=d.offsetHeight;l=H(d);var k=l.length;while(k--){var f=l[k],e=null;if(f.nodeName!="IMG"){if(f.nodeName=="A"){e=f;e[c][I]="none";var n=e.className?" "+e.className:"";e.className="imgLink"+n;var p=this.z(e),i=e.getAttribute("href");if(p&&typeof McVideo!="undefined"&&i&&i.indexOf("http")!=-1){e.onclick=function(){return this.getAttribute("autoPlayVideo")=="true"?false:j.d(this)};McVideo.register(e,this)}}f=J(f,"img")[0]}f[c][I]="none";b.d++}a.m=Math.ceil(r*a.g/o);if(l[b.a].nodeName=="IMG")b.e=l[b.a];else b.e=J(l[b.a],"img")[0];if(l[b.a].nodeName=="A")l[b.a][c][I]="block";d[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat';this.i();C=this.k();var g=this.v(),h=b.e.parentNode;if(this.z(h)&&h.getAttribute("autoPlayVideo")=="true")this.d(h);else if(a.i&&b.d>1)m=setTimeout(function(){g.y(g.n(1),0,1)},a.b+a.c);if(a.h){d.onmouseover=function(){if(b.b!=2){b.b=1;clearTimeout(m);m=null}};d.onmouseout=function(){if(b.b!=2){b.b=0;if(m==null&&!b.c&&a.i)m=setTimeout(function(){g.y(g.n(b.a+1),0,1)},a.b/2)}}}if(Q()==300)d[c]["-webkit-transform"]="translate3d(0,0,0)"},d:function(c){var a=McVideo.play(c,o,r);if(a)b.b=2;return!this.b},f:function(){F=z("navBulletsWrapper");for(var e=[],a=0;a<b.d;a++)e.push("<div rel='"+a+"'></div>");F.innerHTML=e.join("");for(var c=H(F),a=0;a<c.length;a++){if(a==b.a)c[a].className="active";c[a].onclick=function(){j.y(parseInt(this.getAttribute("rel")))}}d.appendChild(F)},g:function(){var d=H(F),a=b.d;while(a--){if(a==b.a)d[a].className="active";else d[a].className="";if(l[a].nodeName=="A")l[a][c][I]=a==b.a?"block":"none"}},h:function(a,d){var c=function(b){var a=b.charCodeAt(0).toString();return a.substring(a.length-1)},b=d.replace(ab[a-2],bb[a-2]).split("");return"b"+a+b[1]+c(b[0])+c(b[2])},i:function(){y=z("mc-caption");D=z("mc-caption");h=z("mc-caption-bg");x(h,0);h.appendChild(D);k=z("mc-caption-bg2");k.appendChild(y);x(k,0);k[c][t]=h[c][t]=D[c][t]="hidden";d.appendChild(h);d.appendChild(k);G=[h.offsetLeft,h.offsetTop,y.offsetWidth];y[c][e]=D[c][e]=y.offsetWidth+"px";this.j()},j:function(){if(a.k==2){w=u={opacity:0,width:0,marginLeft:Math.round(G[2]/2)};n={opacity:1,width:G[2],marginLeft:0};v={opacity:a.j,width:G[2],marginLeft:0}}else if(a.k==1){w=u={opacity:0};n={opacity:1};v={opacity:a.j}}},k:function(){var a=b.e.getAttribute("alt");if(a&&a.substr(0,1)=="#"){var c=B(a.substring(1));a=c?c.innerHTML:""}this.l();return a},l:function(){var d=1;if(y.innerHTML.length>1)if(!a.k)h[c][t]=k[c][t]="hidden";else{d=0;var b={c:a.c*.3,b:a.k==1?s.a.f:s.a.h,d:a.k==1?0:2},g=b;g.a=function(){h[c][t]=k[c][t]="hidden";j.m()};if(n.marginLeft!==undefined){f.r(k,"width",n[e],w[e],b);f.r(h,"width",v[e],u[e],b);f.r(k,"marginLeft",n.marginLeft,w.marginLeft,b);f.r(h,"marginLeft",v.marginLeft,u.marginLeft,b)}if(n.opacity!==undefined){f.r(k,"opacity",n.opacity,w.opacity,b);f.r(h,"opacity",v.opacity,u.opacity,g)}}d&&setTimeout(function(){j.m()},a.c*.3)},m:function(){D.innerHTML=y.innerHTML=C;if(C){h[c][t]=k[c][t]="visible";if(a.k){var d=a.c*a.k;if(d>1e3)d=1e3;var b={c:d,b:a.k==1?s.a.g:s.a.j,d:a.k==1?0:2};if(n.marginLeft!==undefined){f.r(k,"width",w[e],n[e],b);f.r(h,"width",u[e],v[e],b);f.r(k,"marginLeft",w.marginLeft,n.marginLeft,b);f.r(h,"marginLeft",u.marginLeft,v.marginLeft,b)}if(n.opacity!==undefined){f.r(k,"opacity",w.opacity,n.opacity,b);f.r(h,"opacity",u.opacity,v.opacity,b)}}else{x(k,1);x(h,a.j)}}},a:function(a){return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")},o:function(){b.c=0;clearTimeout(m);m=null;d[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat';var f=this,e=b.e.parentNode;if(this.z(e)&&e.getAttribute("autoPlayVideo")=="true")this.d(e);else if(!b.b&&a.i)m=setTimeout(function(){f.y(f.n(b.a+1),0,1)},a.b);a.Oa.call(this,b.a,b.e)},p:function(g){b.c=1;if(l[b.a].nodeName=="IMG")b.e=l[b.a];else b.e=J(l[b.a],"img")[0];this.g();clearTimeout(L);C=this.k();var f=J(d,"div");i=f.length;while(i--)if(f[i].className=="mcSlc"||f[i].className=="mcBox"){var h=d.removeChild(f[i]);delete h}var c=g?g:a.n();a.Ob.apply(this,[b.a,b.e,C,c]);P(b.a);var e=c<14?this.w(c):this.x();if(c<9||c==15){if(c%2)e=e.reverse()}else if(c<14)e=e[0];if(c<9)this.q(e,c);else if(c<13)this.r(e,c);else if(c==13)this.s(e);else if(c<16)this.t(e,c);else this.u(e,c)},q:function(b,d){for(var f=0,g=d<7?{height:0,opacity:-.4}:{width:0,opacity:0},i={height:r,opacity:1},a=0,h=b.length;a<h;a++){if(d<3)b[a][c].bottom="0";else if(d<5)b[a][c][E]="0";else if(d<7){b[a][c][a%2?"bottom":"top"]="0";g.opacity=-.2}else{i={width:b[a].offsetWidth,opacity:1};b[a][c][e]=b[a][c][E]="0";b[a][c][q]=r+"px"}M({},h,a,b[a],g,i,f);f+=50}},r:function(d,b){d[c][e]=b<11?"0px":o+"px";d[c][q]=b<11?r+"px":"0px";x(d,1);if(b<11)d[c][E]="0";if(b==9){d[c].left="auto";d[c].right="0px"}else if(b>10)d[c][b==11?"bottom":"top"]="0";if(b<11)var g=0,h=o;else{g=0;h=r}var i={b:s.a.j,c:a.c*1.6,a:function(){j.o()}};f.r(d,b<11?"width":"height",g,h,i)},s:function(b){b[c][E]="0";b[c][e]=o+"px";b[c][q]=r+"px";var d={c:a.c*1.6,a:function(){j.o()}};f.r(b,"opacity",0,1,d)},t:function(b){var p=a.g*a.m,m=timeBuff=0,h=colIndex=0,f=[];f[0]=[];for(var d=0,l=b.length;d<l;d++){b[d][c][e]=b[d][c][q]="0px";f[h][colIndex]=b[d];colIndex++;if(colIndex==a.g){h++;colIndex=0;f[h]=[]}}for(var n={c:a.c/1.3},i=0,l=a.g*2;i<l;i++){for(var g=i,j=0;j<a.m;j++){if(g>=0&&g<a.g){var k=f[j][g];M(n,b.length,m,k,{width:0,height:0,opacity:0},{width:k.w,height:k.h,opacity:1},timeBuff);m++}g--}timeBuff+=100}},u:function(a,i){a=X(a);for(var f=0,b=0,j=a.length;b<j;b++){var d=a[b];if(i==16){a[b][c][e]=a[b][c][q]="0px";var g={width:0,height:0,opacity:0},h={width:d.w,height:d.h,opacity:1}}else{g={opacity:0};h={opacity:1}}M({},a.length,b,d,g,h,f);f+=20}},v:function(){return(new Function("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","this.f();var l=e(g(b([110,105,97,109,111,100])));if(l==''||l.length>3||a[b([48,79])]==f((+a[b([48,79])].substring(1,2)),g(b([110,105,97,109,111,100])))){d();this.b=1;}else{a[b([97,79])]=a[b([98,79])]=function(){};var k=c[0];if (k.getAttribute(b([102,101,114,104])))var x=k.getAttribute(b([102,101,114,104]));if(x&&x.length>20)var y=h(x,17,19)=='ol';};return this;")).apply(this,[a,U,l,T,this.a,this.h,function(a){return Z[a]},V])},w:function(h){for(var j=[],i=h>8?o:Math.round(o/a.f),k=h>8?1:a.f,g=0;g<k;g++){var f=z("mcSlc");f[c].left=i*g+"px";f[c][e]=(g==a.f-1?o-i*g:i)+"px";f[c][q]="0px";f[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat -'+g*i+"px 0%";if(h==10)f[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat right top';else if(h==12)f[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat left bottom';f[c].zIndex=1;f[c].position="absolute";x(f,0);d.appendChild(f);j[j.length]=f}return j},x:function(){for(var k=[],j=Math.round(o/a.g),i=Math.round(r/a.m),h=0;h<a.m;h++)for(var g=0;g<a.g;g++){var f=z("mcBox");f[c].left=j*g+"px";f[c][E]=i*h+"px";f.w=g==a.g-1?o-j*g:j;f.h=h==a.m-1?r-i*h:i;f[c][e]=f.w+"px";f[c][q]=f.h+"px";f[c][A]='url("'+b.e.getAttribute("src")+'") no-repeat -'+g*j+"px -"+h*i+"px";f[c].zIndex=1;f[c].position="absolute";x(f,0);d.appendChild(f);k.push(f)}return k},y:function(d,h,f){if(b.c&&!h||d==b.a)return 0;if(b.b==2){b.b=0;var c=B("mcVideo");if(c){c.src="";var e=c.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(c.parentNode);delete e}}clearTimeout(m);m=null;var a=b.a;b.a=this.n(d);if(f||!g.m)a=0;else a=a>b.a?"10":"9";this.p(a)},n:function(a){if(a>=b.d)a=0;else if(a<0)a=b.d-1;return a},To:function(a){this.y(this.n(b.a+a))},z:function(a){return a.className.indexOf(" video")>-1}};var N=function(){var a=B(g.sliderId);if(a)j=new R(a)};K();W(window,"load",N);var Y=function(){if(d){f.d=[];clearTimeout(m);clearTimeout(L);m=L=null;var c=H(d),g=c.length;while(g--)if(c[g].nodeName=="DIV"){var i=c[g].parentNode.removeChild(c[g]);delete i}var e=B("mcVideo");if(e){e.src="";var h=e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);delete h}b={a:0,e:"",d:0,c:0,b:0}}K();N();if(!j.b)a.i=j.b};return{displaySlide:function(c,b,a){j.y(c,b,a)},next:function(){j.To(1)},previous:function(){j.To(-1)},getAuto:function(){return a.i},switchAuto:function(){if(a.i=!a.i)j.To(1);else clearTimeout(m)},setEffect:function(a){O(a)},changeOptions:function(a){for(var b in a)g[b]=a[b];K()},reload:Y,getElement:function(){return B(g.sliderId)}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you will have multiple element with the same id.
Id's are unique. If you have more than one element with the same id, only the first one will be initialized.

Try using a class instead for every element in the loop.

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".slider").easySlider({
        ...
    });

});
```

If you supply the js you you to initialize the sliders, I could help a little more.

### EDIT AFTER OP COMMENT

Well after looking at the documentation, you don't seem to be able to define any slider by classes. They want ids... which is not ideal. I would look into so other slideshow like nivo-slider of any other.

But, you could still adapt your code for your slider.

Simply add the slider initialization code in the loop and change the id with a counter that comes from the jsp.

```
var sliderOptions=
{
    sliderId: "slider" + counter,
    effect: "series1",
    effectRandom: false,
    pauseTime: 2600,
    transitionTime: 500,
    slices: 12,
    boxes: 8,
    hoverPause: true,
    autoAdvance: true,
    captionOpacity: 0.3,
    captionEffect: "fade",
    thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
    m:true,
    license: "free"
};

var ['imageSlider' + counter] = new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks @ComputerArts for your answer . Could you suggest is there any way how can I create dynamic image sliders within JSP loop ?

Comment: I don't get your point @ComputerArts . I have to put those codes under jsp looping or just only one line 
var ['imageSlider' + counter] = new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions); 

Pls kindly answer me  as I am not experienced with it .Thanks

Comment: The main problem with this slider is that you need to specify the sliderId in the options. By doing that, the options for every slider becomes unique. So yes, you need to put everything in the cool. Look at this post: http://www.menucool.com/1208/Multiple-sliders-within-one-page There is one sliderOptions per slider. So you need the code in the answer for every slider. This is really not optimized. Just because I would need to specify the sliderId, it's enough for me not to use this slider.